# SQL Error: 241, SQLState: 22007

Tags: sql, hibernate, date, datetime, time

I have a view where I cast a DATETIME to DATE, so I can ignore the time part.

```
CAST(av.date as DATE),
```

I try to query this view on a specific date using the code:

```
s.date BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

To set those parameters I receive the date and truncate it use the following code:

```
DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(bgn);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(end);
Date startDt = DateUtils.truncate(beginDate.toDate(), Calendar.DATE);
Date endDt = DateUtils.truncate(endDate.toDate(), Calendar.DATE);
```

The problem is that when this gets to JDBC, I get the following error:

> WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 241, SQLState: 22007
>   ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The dates are set to the query using the following code:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(name);
query.setParameter("start", startDt);
```

Anyone have any clue about what might be happening?
I found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/8ce22a2c-0cf0-4f17-8d53-232377c41d81/) about this error, but it doesn't help me at all.
I'm 100% lost on this.

Comment: Please update your title to directly reflect your issue. Most people don't know error codes like that off the top of their head.

Comment: Please show code how do you pass dates to query.

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk you can edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the way you pass the dates to query, but you can convert dates to string and then pass it to query:

```
DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(bgn);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(end);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String startDt = df.format(DateUtils.truncate(beginDate.toDate(), Calendar.DATE));
String endDt = df.format(DateUtils.truncate(endDate.toDate(), Calendar.DATE));
```

Without knowing your exact code it is a little bit of guessing.